# Connected Sets in this Topology of $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $$\mathscr{T} = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \, ; \, \pi_y(A) = A_y \, \, \text{is open} \, \}$$ for the projection map $\pi_y: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ in the $y$-coordinate.

How do we characterize open connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in this topology? Clearly a set like $\{1\} \times (0,1)$ is connected, while a  set $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ or $\{0,1\} \times (0,1) $ is not connected.

So, my guess is that, since $\pi_y^{-1} (A_y) = \mathbb{R} \times A_y$, given a set $X$ with more than one $y$-value, such that $\pi_y(X)$ is open, the union $$ X \subset \dot\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} M_x $$ of open sets of the form $M_x = \{x\} \times A_y$ with $x \in X$ are disjoint and contain $X$. Thus, I believe that open connected sets in this topology are those sets that have only one $x$ coordinate and $\pi_y(X)$ is connected.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection of sets is not a topology. The sets 
$$\{(|y|,y)\mid -1<y<1\}$$
and 
$$\{(-|y|,y)\mid -1<y<1\}$$
would be open, but their intersection $\{(0,0)\}$ would not be open.

In general, if $f:X\to Y$ is a function from a set to a topological space, then
$$\{A\subseteq X\mid f(A)\text{ is open in }Y\}$$
does not form a topology.

Comment: Perhaps I messed up then, because the original condition was that $\mathscr{T} =\{ A\subset \mathbb{R}^2; \ \pi_y(A\cap (\{x\} \times \mathbb{R})) \ \mbox{is an open subset of} \ \mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: What is the $x$ in your definition? Some fixed value?

Comment: An element of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: is $\pi_y (A \cap (\{x\} \times \mathbb{R})) \neq A_y?$

Comment: That set could also be written as 
$$\{A\subseteq\Bbb R^2\mid A\cap(\{x\}\times\Bbb R)\text{ is open in }\{x\}\times\Bbb R\}$$
Then it is a special case of a final topology. It's the final topology for the map $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2,\ y\mapsto (x,y)$.

Comment: Why can it not be written as I originally wrote it? i.e as a special case of a product topology?

Comment: Yes, you can also write it the way you did. The other way, one sees that it is a certain final topology.

Comment: No, I mean why is it not the case that $\pi_y (A \cap (\{x\} \times \mathbb{R})) \neq A_y$?

Comment: $π_y(A∩(\{x\}×\Bbb R))$ is not the same as $A_y$. The second set is the projection of all of $A$, and the first set is only what the slice of $x$ "sees" from $A$.

Comment: But doesn't $A \cap (\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}) = \{x\} \times A_y$ or $A \cap (\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}) = \{\emptyset\} \times A_y$ is the projection of these not $A_y$? Are we not just 'throwing away' all $x$ coordinates?

Comment: For the set $A=\{(y,y)\mid 0\le y\le 1\}$, we have $A_y=[0,1]$, but $A\cap\{0\}\times\Bbb R$ just projects to $\{0\}$.

Comment: Would it make a difference if this condition is supposed to hold for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as opposed to a single fixed $x$? I mean if the $x$ values can change, then does it hold that the projection is $A_y$?

Comment: Yes, then it would just be the projection. But that's not a topology as I showed in my answer.

Comment: Are the connected sets in the "special case of the final topology" just all sets connected in the y coordinate in $\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}$? Say, $\{x\} \times [a,b]$?

Comment: Is there a better way to characterize open sets in this space?

Comment: *connected sets I mean

Comment: connected in $\mathcal T=\{A⊂\Bbb R^2; π_y(A∩(\{x\}×\Bbb R))\text{ is an open subset of }\Bbb R\}$ are the sets $\{x\}\times C$, where $C$ is connected in $\Bbb R$. All other sets are not connected.